# Is a multiple part question acceptable if part of it has already been answered

Tags: discussion, moderation

Today, I read this question [Live USB linux distro to backup my Windows machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108703/4671).
My first reaction was to try to help the SExchanger, but then I realized that part of his post had already been answered several times (like how to make a backup).
In that case, should I flag the post as low quality or something or should I try to help anyway?

Also he asks for four very different things. Should those questions be in different posts or not?

Comment: If you are providing a link to a SE question, use the link provided by the share link at the bottom. The actual link is it at can change if the title is changed, as indeed has happened to the question you linked to, since I fixed a typo in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also he asks for 4 very different things and I wondered if those questions should be in different posts or not?

Very much so. You should reach out to him with a comment telling him that multiple questions in one question are not acceptable. What I generally do is I decide which is the "main" question of the post, then edit out all the other ones (with an optional note in the edit summary). If the "main" question already has an answer, then I'd go ahead and flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Well I get your point but still, I'm not really comfortable with the rephrasing of a question as the meaning can be change.

Comment: @Kiwy the idea wasn't to rephrase the question. the idea was to cut out additional questions. if you are rephrasing one of the questions in such a way that the meaning is changed, you're doing it wrong.